# Setting environment variables in Linux using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

In `tcsh`, I have the following script working:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
setenv X_ROOT /some/specified/path

setenv XDB    ${X_ROOT}/db
setenv PATH   ${X_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}

xrun -d xdb1 -i $1 > $2
```

What is the equivalent to the `tcsh setenv` function in Bash?

Is there a direct analog? The environment variables are for locating the executable.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`export VAR=value` will set VAR to value. Enclose it in single quotes if you want spaces, like `export VAR='my val'`. If you want the variable to be interpolated, use double quotes, like `export VAR="$MY_OTHER_VAR"`.

Comment: PS: no need for the double quotes in the last one. The shell does not perform word splitting for variable assignments.

Comment: Just for the beginners. I had not understood it directly, here in normal English: interpolate "$X" means here that you already have a variable X that is filled with a value, e.g. "A", and you want to read out that value "A" first, and then assign this value as the value of VAR. You do not want VAR to be a string of "$X" here of course. And then the comment above seems also logical, that you will not even need the "". And for a direct assignment of "A", use 'A'. Please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: bonus points for the final note about interpolated vars

Answer (score 42):

The reason people often suggest writing

```
VAR=value
export VAR
```

instead of the shorter

```
export VAR=value
```

is that the longer form works in more different shells than the short form.  If you know you're dealing with `bash`, either works fine, of course.

Answer (score 33):

### Set a local and environment variable using Bash on Linux

**Check for a local or environment variables for a variable called LOL in Bash:**

```
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
el@server /home/el $
el@server /home/el $ env | grep LOL
el@server /home/el $
```

Sanity check, no local or environment variable called LOL.

**Set a local variable called LOL in local, but not environment. So set it:**

```
el@server /home/el $ LOL="so wow much code"
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
LOL='so wow much code'
el@server /home/el $ env | grep LOL
el@server /home/el $
```

Variable 'LOL' exists in local variables, but not environment variables.  LOL will disappear if you restart the terminal, logout/login or run `exec bash`.

**Set a local variable, and then clear out all local variables in Bash**

```
el@server /home/el $ LOL="so wow much code"
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
LOL='so wow much code'
el@server /home/el $ exec bash
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
el@server /home/el $
```

**You could also just unset the one variable:**

```
el@server /home/el $ LOL="so wow much code"
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
LOL='so wow much code'
el@server /home/el $ unset LOL
el@server /home/el $ set | grep LOL
el@server /home/el $
```

Local variable LOL is gone.

**Promote a local variable to an environment variable:**

```
el@server /home/el $ DOGE="such variable"
el@server /home/el $ export DOGE
el@server /home/el $ set | grep DOGE
DOGE='such variable'
el@server /home/el $ env | grep DOGE
DOGE=such variable
```

Note that exporting makes it show up as both a local variable and an environment variable.

Exported variable DOGE above survives a Bash reset:

```
el@server /home/el $ exec bash
el@server /home/el $ env | grep DOGE
DOGE=such variable
el@server /home/el $ set | grep DOGE
DOGE='such variable'
```

**Unset all environment variables:**

You have to pull out a can of Chuck Norris to reset all environment variables without a logout/login:

```
el@server /home/el $ export CAN="chuck norris"
el@server /home/el $ env | grep CAN
CAN=chuck norris
el@server /home/el $ set | grep CAN
CAN='chuck norris'
el@server /home/el $ env -i bash
el@server /home/el $ set | grep CAN
el@server /home/el $ env | grep CAN
```

You created an environment variable, and then reset the terminal to get rid of them.

**Or you could set and unset an environment variable manually like this:**

```
el@server /home/el $ export FOO="bar"
el@server /home/el $ env | grep FOO
FOO=bar
el@server /home/el $ unset FOO
el@server /home/el $ env | grep FOO
el@server /home/el $
```

Answer (score 14):

`VAR=value` sets VAR to value.

After that `export VAR` will give it to child processes too.

`export VAR=value` is a shorthand doing both.

Comment: doesn't it give it to parent processes, not childs?  If a shell script does an export, then the shell I invoked it with has that variable, IIRC.

Comment: No. "are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.", meaning child processes executed after the export.

Comment: out of curiousity, where is that citation from?

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for `export` - though I could be wrong.. I've never played with tcsh before. Use the following syntax:

```
export VARIABLE=value
```