# mvn java:exec with increased memory

Tags: java, maven

I use "mvn exec:java" to run my program:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="..." -Dexec.args="..."
```

I didn't find to change the maximum memory allocation to the JVM.

I tried -Dexec.commandlineArgs="..." but that didn't work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598949/maven-heap-space did you try this? MAVEN_OPTS

Comment: Or, as per this http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#arguments you may have to add heap arguments  to the 'arguments'

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13599101/827927 "export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512M" did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*`<commandlineArgs>`* (or *-Dexec.args* when given in the CLI) is for specifying the arguments given to the program, not the JVM.

As **exec:java executes a Java program in the same VM** as the Maven one, just change the Maven JVM memory settings (so **MAVEN_OPTS**) to get more memory for your exec:java command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`exec:exec`** to run `java` in **separate** process.
Then you can specify any arguments (including `-Xmx`).
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25442840/658606 for more details and for an example .