# when i run mvn install ,there is a error

Tags: java, maven

系统资源不足。
    有关详细信息，请参阅以下堆栈追踪。
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.(Manifest.java:315)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.(Manifest.java:310)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:178)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.(Manifest.java:52)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:165)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:146)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:693)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:221)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.fragment(JCDiagnostic.java:158)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.absentKindName(Resolve.java:1486)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$ResolveError.report(Resolve.java:1581)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.access(Resolve.java:1079)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveQualifiedMethod(Resolve.java:1214)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAnnotation(Annotate.java:156)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.enterAnnotations(MemberEnter.java:743)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.access$300(MemberEnter.java:42)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$5.enterAnnotation(MemberEnter.java:711)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:87)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:472)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:429)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:819)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)

```
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.927s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 15 10:28:14 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "Maven" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project pmcs: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
```

Comment: I searched the problem in the internet,it tells me to edit the mvn file in the bin directory,and add the following to the file
        set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
        but it didn't work at all.
        help

Comment: Can you please post the full output of the error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like 512mb is still not enough. Increase the heap memory more. Ex:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

If that don't work, increase more.

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2048m
```

**References:**

[Setting environment variables in Linux using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)

[Setting Java heap space under Maven 2 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819853/setting-java-heap-space-under-maven-2-on-windows)

[Maven heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598949/maven-heap-space)