# how can I set default editor to emacs in unix

Tags: unix, editor

how to make emacs as default editor in bash shell?  I tried setenv EDITOR emacs.  It gave me the error message "setenv:  command not found".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in Linux using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)

Answer (score 0):

When changing profiles, make sure you always use full paths, just in case PATH is not yet set at that point. Double check if you do have setenv:

```
# find / -name setenv
```

If so, just enter its full path in your profile. Furthermore: a unix flavor would be nice for people to know, not all flavors work with the same file names.

Comment: Is it possible to set it up without writing a script though?

Comment: You don't need to write a script, you setup a VI variable in your profile file. I don't know what unix flavor you are using so I cannot help you with the right file.

Comment: P.s. you can also create a symbolic link from emacs to "vi" and make sure the symbolic link "vi" comes before the emacs location in your PATH variable. :-)

Comment: which flavor, not sure what you mean?  I'm in a bash shell.  And I'm not sure if's available on this system.  I type in emacs at command line, and it says emacs command not found.

Comment: In that case your question was misleading: you want emacs and it's not found: simply install emacs then.