# Setting up Environment Variable for GCP

Tags: python, environment-variables, google-cloud-platform

I read [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) article but I still don't understand how I have to set up the environment variable with the `.json` file with the credentials. Do I have to enter something in the Terminal or write something in my Python code?

Also, is the path relative to the user directory? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do either: the key part is that the environmental variable must be present for the SDK to pick up in the code that you're running. You could set it programmatically in Python ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)) or in your terminal ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)), depending on what you want to do. You just need the process that's executing your code to have the variable set in *its* environment.

Use an absolute path.