# It always works by default, regardless of the script being run

Tags: javascript, node.js

Default is always executed, regardless of the script being run.

Here is my code:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import config from './../config';

const connectionString = () => {
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
        case 'development': console.log('0'); return config.db_dev.connectionString;
        case 'production': console.log('1'); return config.db_prod.connectionString;
        case 'test': console.log('2'); return config.db_test.connectionString;
        default: console.log('3'); return config.db_dev.connectionString;
    }
}

export default new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString(),
    ssl: true,
});
```

File `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "devbuild": "SET NODE_ENV=development & babel src --out-dir dev-hyperspotters-backend",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production & babel src --out-dir hyperspotters-backend",
    "test": "SET NODE_ENV=test & mocha --timeout 10000 --require @babel/register"
  },
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: How can I transfer the database link to pol correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash
Try `export NODE_ENV=test; mocha...`

Comment: Could you run one of the scripts directly in your terminal? For example: `NODE_ENV=development & node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir dev-hyperspotters-backend && node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/index.js` see if this works?

Comment: I ran and it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js

Comment: Then, just as @ponsfrilus suggested, the environment variable is not being set properly. Use `export NODE_ENV` as suggested, or use a library like dotenv

Comment: @MegaRoks - What OS are you using? Looks like Windows, but... (If you're on \*nix, ponsfrilus is right about the env var.)

Comment: `&` would be the wrong thing to do in Linux at least - not sure about windoze

Comment: I don't think the capital set is needed. And also, just use `;` instead of `&`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090755/960623

Comment: I use OS windows

Comment: @ponsfrilus `And also, just use ; instead of &. Check this answer` - that answer uses NEITHER ; nor & ... - did you link to the wrong answer?

Comment: @Jaromanda X mistake

Comment: @MegaRoks just use this, it's cross platform: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @Baruch How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the connectionString is not passed to the function.

```
    const connectionString = (process.env.NODE_ENV) => {
        switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
            case 'development':
                return 0
            case 'production':
                return 1
            case 'test':
                return 2
            default:
                return 3
        }
    }

Pool = {
    connectionString: connectionString(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    ssl: true
}
```

Comment: Gives an error to the function `Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters`. Shows it `=> {`

Comment: Can you share with us what the content of the left hand side is?

Comment: I fixed this error; the `developmentMode` variable was adopted in the function, but this did not solve my problem. The `default` branch is still executed.

Comment: Great. So now the process.env.NODE_ENV is adopted in the function, I assume. Can you verify that it is actual a string holing one of the cases the switch expression is checking on?