# How to setevn bash command from python script

Tags: python, bash, automation

I am trying to do the following:

```
setenv PRJ_ROOT /home/to/proj_dir
setenv VAR1 /home/user/john/to/proj_dir/design_files
setenv VAR2 /home/user/john/to/proj_dir/model_files
....
....
....
setenv VARN /home/user/john/to/proj_dir/random_files
```

So, if I have all the above commands in a file say "setup" I can simply call "source setup" to set all the env variable. But Now i wish to make it generic with respect to the path.

I have tried subprocess.call and os.environ to set up the path but didn't get any success. My code is below. I am quite new to python and trying to build on this skill, please guide.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
cmd1 = "setenv VAR1 path"
cmd2 = "setenv VAR1 path"
...
...
...
path = os.getcwd()
var1Path = path + '/design_files'
var2Path = path + '/model_files'
...
...
...

#try 1
os.environ['VAR1'] = var1Path
os.environ['VAR2'] = var2Path
....
....

#try 2
subprocess.call(cmd1, shell=True)
#(or)
subprocess.call(cmd1, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
#(or)
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash','-i','-c', cmd1])
#(or)
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', cmd])

#NOTE: tried both /bin/sh and also /bin/bash
```

Expected result:
after the running script, if I do "echo $VAR1" output should be the complete path.

Actual result:

```
/bin/sh: setenv: command not found
(or)
bash: setenv: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

`setenv` is not valid keyword in **bash** shell, try `export`

here is some help:

[Setting environment variables in Linux using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)

Comment: we could add the function `setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }`

Answer (score 1):

I think your intention might be to set variables in the environment of the parent, which is **not possible**.

Other answers show how you can set them for children.

Therefore, if you want to set environment variables of your current `bash` you can create a script that *spits* the sentences and then you eval them.

```
$ ./setenv.py
export VAR1=path
export VAR2=path
```

then

```
$ eval $(./setenv.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing your shells.  'setenv' is part of csh and not part of bash.

If I understand your requirement, you want to set some variables in the python process' environment, and make them available to child processes.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

path=os.getcwd()

var1Path=path+'/design_files'
var2Path=path+'/model_files'

os.environ['VAR1']=var1Path
os.environ['VAR2']=var2Path

cmd1='echo $VAR1 $VAR2'
print 'cmd1='+cmd1
subprocess.call(cmd1,shell=True)
```

Result is:

```
echo $VAR1 $VAR2
/var/tmp/design_files /var/tmp/model_files
```

The subprocess knows about the bash variables.