# How do I set java_opts environment variables on mac?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

For windows in bat file for wildfly application I was setting as 
`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.home=..../x/y/pathToApplication"`

My requirement is to set the same in mac in shell script file. Tried several ways from google but couldn't get it work.

So I tried 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djboss.home=/Users/.../Documents/...cloud/.../wildfly" - it worked

but when I set another variable 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyapp.home=/Users/.../Documents/...cloud/.../myapp" - it overrides the first one

Next I tried 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djboss.home=/Users/.../Documents/...cloud/.../wildfly" - it worked but has overridden the previous value.

So I tried 
export JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.home=/Users/.../Documents/../cloud/.../wildfly"
export JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Dmyapp.home=/Users/.../Documents/cloud/dev/deployments/supervisor"

But then shell script fails and terminates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variables in Linux using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)

Comment: already tried, didn't work
Thank you @Quentin

Comment: Then show a [mcve]

Comment: Basically I am looking out for equivalent of -> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.home=..../x/y/pathToApplication" ( windows bat file )

Comment: I asked for a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem with your attempt, not a repetition of code that works on a different platform that you already provided.

Comment: Ok going through the document and trying to draft :)

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

In mac it will be of below format
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=32m"

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-community-install-guide/v56/setting-jvm-options-application